# How to make a video in Linux/Python/Opengl?

Tags: python, linux, opengl

How to save video in python OpenGL? Are there any ready-made solutions? Without using 3D or video editors

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each frame of the video, render the picture, preferrably to a framebuffer object (to avoid image corruption from failed window pixel ownership tests). Read out image using `glReadPixels`, submit to video encoder.

Choices for video encoders are broad. On Linux *ffmpeg* is widely available, so you can just use that. Most straightforward way is to spawn *ffmpeg* as a process (see the Python module "`subprocess`") with appropriate command line options to read raw images from stdin and write out to whatever destination you desire, then write the images rendered with OpenGL to the ffmpeg process' stdin.